# A linear algebra problem on minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose for a linear map $T$ in complex vector space $V$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the distinct eigenvalues such that $(T-\lambda_1 I)(T-\lambda_2 I)$=0. I need to prove that $ker(T-\lambda_1 I)^{dimV}=ker(T-\lambda_1 I)$. Hint is enough.

Comment: You can look at the Jordan normal form of a representation of the map.

Comment: Or use the Bezout coefficients of the two factors of the minimal polynomials, to get a projection on $ker(T-\lambda_1I)$.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is doing what sebigu proposes in his first comment: your map is diagonalizable (why?) and $\;T-\lambda_iI\;$ is easy to handle then...